# Location Request on Android Google Map, setIntervals() and if it costs anything

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, location, google-maps-android-api-2

```
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

Setting this to 1000 ms, requests location every second and accumulates to thousands of requests in a day if app is used continuously. Will this cost me and will making less location requests than this cost me less?
I am working on an app which requires to get the drivers location. I would just like to clarify if setting shorter location request interval will cost  me anything. The links given below did help but did not answer what I was actually looking for.

The second link on the costs stated on Google developers site talks about Places API and its costs. What I exactly want to know on point is that does Google charge anything on location request and its intervals?

[Android Google Services Location costs and limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29500651/android-google-services-location-costs-and-limitations)

https://developers.google.com/places/android/usage

What I actually want to achieve is to move my marker on the map in real-time. I can do this by setting intervals which works as delays. I had read somewhere that moving the marker in real-time might cost me. Can I get clarification on this...

Thank you

Comment: I believe [`LocationRequest()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest) and `Places API` are two different thing, but it does compliment each other. Places API is one of the Google Maps Platform APIs that is used to get information on specific places and has its own way of getting billed (the billing doc on Places API has no mentions of the LocationRequest): https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/usage-and-billing

Comment: Thank you for the response @jabamataro. Still I am not having a clear idea about the billing if I am requesting location every 1000ms or every second. Does this request and the frequency of it costs me??

Comment: No I believe not. `LocationRequest()` is part of the Google Play Services which I believe is free. You can check the doc here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview